# JSONB replace value of a specific key Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replace, jsonb

I need to replace the values of specific keys inside a jsonb object in Postgresql:

```
create table content (
  id int,
  dynamic_fields jsonb
  );
  
insert into content values (0, '{
    "key1": "aaaaa text1",
    "key2": "text1",
    "key3": "blabla"}'::jsonb);

UPDATE content 
SET dynamic_fields = replace(dynamic_fields::text, 'text1', 'text2')::jsonb;
```

This code up here gives the following result:

```
id |    dynamic_fields  
0  |  {"key1": "aaaaa text2", "key2": "text2", "key3": "blabla"}
```

Instead of replacing all the occurrences of "text1", I'd like to replace only that text inside the value of "key1": how do I do it?

The result of the update should be something like:

```
id |    dynamic_fields  
0  |  {"key1": "aaaaa text1", "key2": "text2", "key3": "blabla"}
```

UPDATED the desired outcome, it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_build_object()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html)

```sql
update content
set dynamic_fields = 
    dynamic_fields || 
    jsonb_build_object('key1', replace(dynamic_fields->>'key1', 'text1', 'text2'))
where dynamic_fields ? 'key1'
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dca98b65f5b518d56e62a1f0c0d8ac95)

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator **||** to contact two JSON data and generate new JSON data.
Now we can use **||** to join old JSON data to new JSON data (Like: `{"key2": "text2"}`)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3616a29688cbaf0c2ba8066077d18e38)

```sql
update content
set dynamic_fields = dynamic_fields || '{"key2": "text2"}'::jsonb;
```

**P.S:**

Also, you can use `jsonb_set` function to change data.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9b99bc96b2a415fbe6ec2dd443415ecf)

```sql
update content
set dynamic_fields = jsonb_set(dynamic_fields, '{key2}', '"text2"');
```

Comment: I want the existing text to stay intact, so this works only if the value is "text1" and I want to change it to "text2", but if I have "aaaaaa text1" and I want to change it to "aaaaaa text2" it doesn't work. I need to replace a portion of the string, not to update the whole string.